# Remove file trailer record using scalding or scala

Tags: scala, bigdata, scalding

I am trying to use Pipe (cascading.pipe.Pipe) for reading a file. 
Every record in file follows a schema except trailer record hence; whenever the pipe reading code executes, it throws exception as trailer record doesn't match with schema.
The Pipe line looks like :

fieldlst:List(col1, col2, col3)

val filteredInput = Csv(inputFilePath, separator = "|", fields = fieldlst, skipHeader = true)
    .read

Can anybody tell me a solution for this. Removing trailer record by read-write file seems to be a simple solution but for that, I have to read-write entire file and file can be very huge.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Csv pipe, you can use TextLine and then split your records using '|'.

Comment: Thanks satendra !!! that did work but when I read file using TextLine and write back it includes sequence values at start of each row e.g. 1,2,3... How can I avoid this or is there a way with which it simple not write the file after reading ? Note :- I am overriding FlowListener while executing TextLine.